# User inventory database design?

Tags: mysql

I'm making a game in PHP with MySQL and I was wondering what is the best way for me to store the items the users have purchased so it is linked with their account.

I plan to have a database with the items information in and the only ways I could think of doing it was:

1. Having a table for the users items in a serialised array of sort
2. Having masses of columns with a set amount of inventory space
3. Table with user_id and item_id and add a row every time they purchase an item, selecting the user_id relevant to the user to display their items

Which is best?

Comment: IMHO you should have at least three tables: USERS table, ITEMS table and USERITEMS table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you know at the beginning which items a user can buy, so in my opinion you should have three tables

- **USERS** table, in which you store user data (`PRIMARY KEY` is **user_id**)
- **ITEMS** table, in which you store items with their cost and data (`PRIMARY KEY` is **item_id**)
- **USERITEMS** table, in which you store every item bought by users. It should have two columns: **user_id** and **item_id** and you add a row every time a user buy an item.

This design lets you easily manage bought items and show every user its inventory.
More: you avoid wasting space in database duplicating unuseful informations

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought this might be the best way of doing it, I always try to remove duplicating information that isn't needed just wanted some reassurance that was the best way of doing it. I worry that masses of rows will really drag down the database, but on reading it you can have loads of rows without a big affect on performance.

Comment: @Silenced: having primary keys and indexes correctly set, querying database (even with billions rows) could be surprisingly fast. For what I can imagine, you should use `SELECT i.* FROM ITEMS i INNER JOIN USERITEMS ui ON i.item_id = ui.item_id INNER JOIN USERS u ON ui.user_id = u.user_id WHERE u.user_id = ???`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, the No.3 is suitable.I prefer @Marco suggestion.